# Display a modal once per session using the sessionstorage function

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I have a modal on a page which makes use of javascript to display once the page has loaded, however, on refresh, I would like this modal to not be repeated as it can be a bit of a nuisance.

I have done some research and found a method using 'sessionstorage' but the problem is I don't know how to incorporate it into my code. My java is very poor.

Excerpt of my modal html and Javascript code below.

```
   <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div  class="modal-dialog">  
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="text-left-side">
                    <b>Check out your order now </b><br><br>                                                                        
                 </p>
          </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><b>Close<b></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<!-- sCRIPT FOR THE PAGE LOAD MODAL -->
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function(){       
         setTimeout(function(){ $('#myModal').modal('show'); }, 1400);
         });
     </script>
```

Comment: And Java is not JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

Few mistakes.

1. Use `$(document).ready()` function.
2. Use `localStorage` and set a flag. If it is set, don't display modal. Display only when it is not set.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function() {
  if (typeof Storage != "undefined") {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("done")) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
      }, 1400);
    }
    localStorage.setItem("done", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="text-left-side">
          <b>Check out your order now </b><br><br>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><b>Close<b></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code will not execute in Snippets because of sandboxing. Kindly check with your code.

You can check the working demo at [**JSBin**](http://output.jsbin.com/qekenalapi). Be careful. It works only once. `:D`